# Convert an image from bytes in xml to word document

Tags: c#, xml, image, ms-word

I've created an application in c# where an image is inserted into xml by turning it into bytes. How do i then convert this image from the xml into a word document?

Answer (score 0):

This article might help you:

- [Inserting images into Word documents using XML](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4677/inserting-images-into-word-documents-using-xml/)

The main idea of the article is to construct a `WordML` (WordProcessingML) document fragment representing the image to be inserted and then calling Word's `InsertXML` function to place the image in the document.

Comment: does this do it instead of converting it into bytes and base64 string then?

Comment: In the `PictWriter` class the image is represented as a byte array. The `InsertXML` method then just takes this XML as a string and adds it into Word. If I understand your question correct, this is exactly what you're searching for.